# Python Dice Program, Random integer not changing

Tags: python, random, dice

I am trying to write a small bit of code, that makes a number of throws of a dice and then records the number of 6's rolled. As you can imagine i'm using random.randint(1,6). However the random integer is simply repeated for each consecutive throw. I am guessing it could be the structure of the while loop I have, i'm a total newbie to this so any help would be much appreciated.

```
#import random module
import random

#introduce the program
print("a program to count the number of 6's thrown in a simulation of a dice being thrown 6000 times")

#declare the variables
max = int(6) #need to declare max number for the dice
min = int(1) #need to declare min number for the dice
throw = random.randint(1,6) #each throw of the dice generates a number
countThrow = 0 #count the number of throws
maxThrow = int(6) #max throw
sixRolled = 0 #count the number of 6's thrown

#while loop

while countThrow != maxThrow:
    countThrow = countThrow + 1
    print(throw)
    print("Number of rolls ", countThrow)

    if throw == 6:
        sixRolled = sixRolled + 1
        print("You have thrown a", throw)

    else:
        print("you have rolled a", throw, "roll again.")
        

print("You have rolled ", sixRolled, "6's in 6 throws")
```

Many thanks

Comment: Somehow it's a common misconception about randomness, but when you write `throw = random.randint(1,6)`, it simply does a single, actual dice roll. So it's not some magic that `throw` becomes "random", always showing something else when you check, but it will store a single number, until you put something else into it. That's why the `throw = random.randint(1,6)` should go inside the loop.

Comment: In addition to some advise in the comments here is my 2 cents. You can make your code more concise by using a for loop instead of a while loop. This would be : 
for throw in range(maxThrow):
    throw = random.randint(1,6)
    ...

Comment: Thanks alot guys, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because you only call `throw = random.randint(1,6)`  once

You need to add this into the loop to keep generating random numbers.

```
#import random module
import random

#introduce the program
print("a program to count the number of 6's thrown in a simulation of a dice being thrown 6000 times")

#declare the variables
max = int(6) #need to declare max number for the dice
min = int(1) #need to declare min number for the dice

countThrow = 0 #count the number of throws
maxThrow = int(6) #max throw
sixRolled = 0 #count the number of 6's thrown

#while loop

while countThrow != maxThrow:
    throw = random.randint(1,6) #each throw of the dice generates a number
    countThrow = countThrow + 1
    print(throw)
    print("Number of rolls ", countThrow)

    if throw == 6:
        sixRolled = sixRolled + 1
        print("You have thrown a", throw)

    else:
        print("you have rolled a", throw, "roll again.")
        

print("You have rolled ", sixRolled, "6's in 6 throws")
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the random in the while loop.
please see the following code where i inserted the random in the loop.

```
while countThrow != maxThrow:
    countThrow = countThrow + 1
    throw = random.randint(1, 6) # you should insert the random in the loop
    print(throw)
    print("Number of rolls ", countThrow)

    if throw == 6:
        sixRolled = sixRolled + 1
        print("You have thrown a", throw)

    else:
        print("you have rolled a", throw, "roll again.")
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, much appreciated